# Javascript how to get child node from parent - Child node appears in nodelist but can't be retrieved

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child

```js
let div = document.getElementById('parentId');

// This will return a nodeList with the child div         
console.log(div.childNodes);

// This will return an undefined
console.log(div.firstChild);

// This will return 0
console.log(div.childNodes.length);
```

```html
<div id="parentId" class="column-">
    <div class="item water" id="childId"></div>
</div>
```

I am building a javascript application which uses an MVC structure.
Now that i am trying to retrieve data from a div

This div has a childnode when i console.log(div.childNodes)

The childnode appears but when i try to retrief the childnode it self 
I constaly get an undefined back 
And when i try to use length it returns 0

Have gone to a long list of possible ways to retrief a childenode but i never seems to gives me the childenode only the undefined and 0 length

I have search for how to retrief a childenode, best ways to retrieve a childnode and plenty more but none of the solutions solves my problem

Result out put: https://pasteboard.co/IkrPqqa.jpg

I would suspect that one of these will return the first childe node
But instead it returns undefined

Does anybody see what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Post code here as a runnable snipped (reduced to a minimum, including the HTML). Images are useless.

Comment: post your html that goes with the js

Comment: @RobG But this shows the results that i am getting

Comment: But it doesn't show how you get them. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The code you've added to the question doesn't produce the results you say it does. E.g. `div.childNodes.length` returns 3.

Comment: @RobG is this a improvement, i am still not fully certain what you mean with
it isn't clear enough.

I can't retrief the child from a parent
node.

While when i check the childeNode nodelist it does appear in the list

How could i formulate the question better?

Comment: @RobG does it exactly return three or was this just an example?

Comment: @questions it returns 3 in your snippet which makes sense (1 element node and 2 text nodes which are there because of formatted html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select the child, use ".children[index]"

```
document.querySelector("#parentId").children[0];
```

Comment: Is there an error  or  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null at <anonymous>:1:3**

Answer (score 0):

Everthing seems to be right. I have run your code it works for me. I have attached the picture of output for your code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parentId" class="column-">
    <div class="item water" id="childId">12</div>
</div>

<script>

let div = document.getElementById('parentId');
    console.log(div.childNodes);

// This will return an undefined
console.log(div.firstChild);
console.log(div.firstElementChild);
console.log(div.childNodes[0]);
console.log(div.childNodes['0']);
console.log(div.childNodes["0"]);

// This will return 0
console.log(div.childNodes.length);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Image of output]

Answer (score 0):

There are many kinds of node types (Element node, Text node, ...).

If you only need to retrieve Element nodes (e.g. "div"), you can do the following:

```
let div = document.getElementById('parentId');

var lengthChildren = div.childNodes.length;

for (var i = 0; i < lengthChildren; i++) {
  // Only node type "Element node"
  if (div.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1)
  {
    console.log(div.childNodes[i]);
  }
}
```

For a list of node types, look here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType

Answer (score 0):

Nodes and Elements are not the same thing in HTML. While an Element is a Node, a Node is not always an Element.

Handy Element getter functions:

- [ParentNode.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)
- [ParentNode.firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild)
- [ParentNode.lastElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/lastElementChild)
- [Document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [Element.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName)
- [Element.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)
- [Element.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)
- [Element.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

Below I refactored the given code to get the desired results.

```js
let div = document.getElementById('parentId');

/*
// This will return a nodeList with the child div         
console.log(div.childNodes);

// This will return an undefined
console.log(div.firstChild);

// This will return 0
console.log(div.childNodes.length);
*/

// This will return an HTMLCollection with the child div         
console.log(div.children);

// This will return the child div element
console.log(div.firstElementChild);

// This will return 1
console.log(div.children.length);
```

```html
<div id="parentId" class="column-">
    <div class="item water" id="childId"></div>
</div>
```